# How can I create a new table by deleted duplicated rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks like this

```
ID A B C 
1  1 0 0
1  1 0 0
2  1 1 0
2  1 1 0
```

How can I remove the duplicated rows in SQL so that I am left with a table that looks like this:

```
ID A B C 
1  1 0 0
2  1 1 0
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949/5059690

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as rn
from tablename
)

delete from cte where rn<>1
```

Comment: I received an errpr stating row number must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY. how can I alter the code to overcome this error

Comment: @Beum, it's already have that, what is your sql server version

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct * from <table_name>
```

This is the simplest way.